# How do I pass an argument to a PlatonScript procedure

Tags: arguments, procedure, jplaton

Does anyone know how to pass a local variable to PlatonScript procedure as an argument?
I just don't want to use global variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a procedure that has parameters you have to declare it like

```
<p_targetsData>
        <![CDATA[START:p_targetsData(testvar1,testvar2)


        testvar1 = "test"
        testvar2 = 123

        RETURN 1 ]]>
 </p_targetsData>
```

when you want to call it and pass the parameters you write

```
@testvar1:STRING
@testvar2:INTEGER
CALL p_targetsData(testvar1,testvar2)
```

jPlaton uses calling by reference so after the CALL execution your variables will still have their real value